# Креатив и творчество

Tags: синонимы

Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли слово "креатив" полным синонимом слова "творчество"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "креатив" в буквальном переводе означает "созидание", "результат созидательной деятельности". В семантике этого слово присутствует и элемент творчества, однако, думаю, это не одинаковые по значению слова. Креативный - это деятельный, активный, склонный к созиданию,в том числе и с компонентами творчества, но все же не синоним творчества

Answer (score 1):

"Креатив" в современном молодежном и профессиональном арго означает результат какой-либо авторской деятельности (чаще литературной, драматической, кинодраматическоой и т.д.), претендующий на оригинальность, значимость и т.д. 
"Не креатив" - негативная оценка, мягкая форма для "аффтырь, выпей йаду!".

Answer (score 1):

Креатив - что-то новаторское, собственное видение автора. Часто расходится с общепринятыми нормами. Бывает немыслимым и иногда смешным.

Answer (score 0):

В современном русском языке можно видеть, как со временем слово по своему употреблению всё дальше и дальше уходит от первоначального смысла. И если со словом "творческий", в принципе, всё понятно - оно устоялось в языке, так как бытует в нём уже очень давно, да и внешняя форма однозначно связывает его со словом "творчество", то со словом "креативный" далеко не всё так ясно. Да, в буквальном переводе это - "результат созидательной деятельности". Но вот если при приёме на работу вам говорят: "нам требуются креативные молодые люди", то это значит, что ваша должность в переводе на нормальный русский язык будет обозначаться как "не пришей кобыле хвост", а заработная плата хоть и высокая, но где и как её раздобыть - это ваши проблемы, фирма не гарантирует, что вы хоть что-то получите. А вот если говорят: "нам требуются креативные девушки" - это значит, что от вас потребуют в том числе и сексуальных услуг, и вообще словосочетание "креативная девушка" является не показателем творческого потенциала этой девушки, а синонимом выражения "девушка по вызову". Поэтому слово "креативный" выглядит "сниженным" по сравнению со словом "творческий": писатели, музыканты, художники, учёные - творят, а "занимаются креативом" (уродливое словосочетание, звучащее совершенно не по-русски!) исключительно рекламные агенты, менеджеры и акционисты.